# How to fix IP-Based voting?

Tags: php

I have IP based voting code, but the problem is when I vote from my computer ( connected to the internet using the same network ) I can't !!

Here is the code :

```
global $wpdb;
$post_ID = $_POST['id'];
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$irt_textOnclick = get_option('irt_textOnclick');
$recommend = get_post_meta($post_ID, '_recommended', true);

if($post_ID != '') {
    $voteStatusByIp = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."irecommendthis_votes WHERE post_id = '$post_ID' AND ip = '$ip'");

    if (!isset($_COOKIE['recommended-'.$post_ID]) && $voteStatusByIp == 0) {
        $recommendNew = $recommend + 1;
        update_post_meta($post_ID, '_recommended', $recommendNew);

        setcookie('recommended-'.$post_ID, time(), time()+3600*24*365, '/');
        $wpdb->query("INSERT INTO ".$wpdb->prefix."irecommendthis_votes VALUES ('', NOW(), '$post_ID', '$ip')");

        $return_text = $recommendNew . ' ' . $irt_textOnclick;
        echo $return_text; //$recommendNew; // 
    }
    else {
        $return_text = $recommend . ' ' . $irt_textOnclick;
        echo $return_text; //$recommendNew; //  
    }
}
```

Comment: Your IP is probably the same each time, and your script only allows one vote per IP...check the `irecommendthis_votes` table for your IP.

Comment: Why can't you? Are you getting errors? Are you behind a proxy server? You'll need to provide more information on what the problem is.

Comment: I think the problem here is that other computers on the same network cannot vote because they use the same public ip addr

Comment: no errors ! and no proxy server !

Comment: isn't that the whole point of your code ? Not to allow multiple votes from the same IP ?

Comment: No, I want to allow each computer to vote only once !

Comment: That may not work for multiple people behind the same router, such as an office or home network. You may want to set a cookie on the user's system instead.

Comment: if you notice I am using the booth ! cookie and IP, because the user may delete the cookies !

Comment: Nice SQL injection hole. Enjoy having your blog pwn3d.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using both cookies and IP checks to prevent multiple voting, then votes cannot be done more than once for computers sharing the same IP address. That would prevent other users in the same network from making votes, since you would be considered as having one IP address.